# Get data from all child node's child id firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the json structure I am using:

```
|-a
  |--date1
     |--uid1
     |--uid2
  |--date2
     |--uid3
  |--date3
     |--uid1
```

I need to get uid1 for all dates. How ,to query for the same using firebase .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from Firebase Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541098/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-database)

Comment: Is uid1 a key or value within each date node? If it's a value, what is it's key?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to duplicate your data structure like:

```
|-a
  |--date1
    |--uid1
    |--uid2
  |--date2
    |--uid3
  |--date3
    |--uid1
|-a-uid1
  |--date1
  |--date3
```

This kind of duplication is quite common for NoSQL databases and it will provide you the best performance (query response time)